# Private inheritance and access

Tags: c++

I was looking at this question below at the back of my book and it got me a little confused. this would be false right?

In private inheritance, all public and protected members of the base class can be accessed in the derived class, but are not accessible through the derived class.

Comment: It sounds mainly true (depending on the meaning of "through the derived class".) Why do you think it is false?

Comment: Why do you think this would be false? Is that not what should happen?

Comment: I repeated this plenty of times as a comment on SO: if you have any questions about how public/protected/private inheritance works, this is THE link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/860339/3093378 (check the most voted answer) The only type of inheritance I cannot get (and I truly think is more than obscure) is `protected` inheritance. Maybe someone can illuminate me on why would it be useful. I am voting to close your question as afaik it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/860339/3093378

Answer (score 1):

This is true. The subclass can use base class methods internally. But the methods of the base class would not be accessible from an instance of the derived class.

```
void Subclass::baseClassMethodOverride()
{
    useBaseClassMethod(); //<---- ALLOWED
}

int main()
{
    SubClass instance;
    instance.useBaseClassMethod(); //<-----NOT ALLOWED
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's true.

If you have a `public` or `protected` member you can access them in the derived class irregardless of the access modifier of the inheritance

Answer (score 1):

That is by definition what private inheritance is. For example, N4140 explains:

> §11.2/1 [...] If a class is declared to be a base class for another
>   class using the `private` access specifier, the `public` and
>   `protected` members of the base class are accessible as `private`
>   members of the derived class<sup>115</sup>.

Furthermore,

> §11/1  A member of a class can be
>
> — `private`; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends
>   of the class in which it is declared.

The phrase "but are not accessible through the derived class." is a little vague, but if the intended meaning is "can't be accessed outside of the derived class except for `friend`s", then it's true.

Note: read the access specifier as appertaining to inheritance. i.e., private inheritance means what it inherits is private, not that it inherits private members.